# INSERT INTO with empty results from SELECT

Tags: mysql, select, insert

I'm trying to insert into table A from the results gather from table B:

```
INSERT INTO A (x, y, created_at) 
(SELECT x, "something", a_timestamp 
FROM B WHERE c IS NULL AND a_timestamp > NOW())
```

The issue is that, for some instances

```
(SELECT x, "something", a_timestamp 
FROM B WHERE c IS NULL AND a_timestamp > NOW())
```

doesn't return any records (which is okay), but then the other INSERT fails.

How can I cover myself from that scenario?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you do the select beforehand and do a count on the number of rows returned? If it is greater than 0 then do the above.

Comment: I could, but that wouldn't be that efficient. In case there are more than 0 records, I'd be doing the select again for the insert.

Comment: see my revised answer

Comment: This looks vaguely like Ruby. When composing SQL statements be sure to use placeholder values for any user data. You can also use SQL functions like `UTC_TIMESTAMP()` in place of `current_time`.

Comment: I'll update my question so you don't get confused by the ruby bit, @tadman

Comment: Not confused, just highly concerned. You need to be careful with these things or [bad things happen](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce the error:

```sql
mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tbl_test`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_test` (
    ->   `id` TINYINT
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `tbl_test`
    -> SELECT 1
    -> FROM DUAL
    -> WHERE 0 = 0;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT `id` FROM `tbl_test`;
+------+
| id   |
+------+
|    1 |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `tbl_test`
    -> SELECT 1
    -> FROM DUAL
    -> WHERE 0 = 1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT `id` FROM `tbl_test`;
+------+
| id   |
+------+
|    1 |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**UPDATE**

```sql
mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tbl_test`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_test` (
    ->   `id` TINYINT
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `tbl_test`
    ->   (`id`)
    -> VALUES
    ->   (101);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT `id`
    -> FROM `tbl_test`;
+------+
| id   |
+------+
|  101 |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `tbl_test`
    -> SELECT `id` + 1
    -> FROM `tbl_test`
    -> WHERE `id` > 100;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT `id`
    -> FROM `tbl_test`;
+------+
| id   |
+------+
|  101 |
|  102 |
+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `tbl_test`
    -> SELECT `id` + 1
    -> FROM `tbl_test`
    -> WHERE `id` < 100;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT `id`
    -> FROM `tbl_test`;
+------+
| id   |
+------+
|  101 |
|  102 |
+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xjaFaG68ySoVtAJoVPwtA7/0).

Comment: You queries are not a reflection of my issue, use a real data conditional (like WHERE id > 100) in your WHERE clause when doing the SELECT.

Comment: @content01: Post the data of your tests to facilitate the work.

Comment: @content01: Updated answer with a conditional close to that indicated by you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `INSERT IGNORE INTO` to address your issue.

For example:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO A (x, y, created_at) 
(SELECT x, "something", a_timestamp 
FROM B WHERE c IS NULL AND a_timestamp > NOW())
```

More info can be found [here](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-insert-ignore/)

Answer (score -1):

```
"INSERT INTO A (x, y, created_at) 
(SELECT x, \"something\", a_timestamp 
FROM B WHERE c IS NULL AND a_timestamp > \"#{current_time}\")
```

To

```
"INSERT INTO A (x, y, created_at) 
(SELECT x, \"something\", a_timestamp 
FROM B WHERE c IS NULL AND a_timestamp > \"#{current_time}\")
AND (SELECT count(x) FROM B WHERE c IS NULL AND a_timestamp > \"#{current_time}\")) > 0"
```

Comment: If the SELECT statement returns no records, a coalesce will not help. Furthermore, I get the impression that OP does not want a record produced when the SELECT statement produces 0 records. OP merely wants to not receive an error in this condition.

Comment: Correct, I don't want to insert anything, just want it to "fail" silently. @JNevill